# How to set routes from angular 5 project to its node_modules project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-module

I am having two angular projects as **A** and **B**. I had converted **B** as node package using **packgr**. Then I have added **B** as dependency to **A**. Now I need to create routes as child in **A** and it should load as root in **B**.

```
project A
RouterModule.forRoot(projectB-Routes)

Project B
RouterModule.forChild(Routes[]);
```

Can anyone help me in achieving this? Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It seems really wrong that you would have routes in an NPM package. Are you sure you're doing it right?

Comment: Try create 2 different modules and import one into the other

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I am having a use case where I need to add projectB to other 10 projects I have. So that if I add that to node_modules, i can access with all changes whenever that happen to projectB. If this is not correct architecture please help me to get one? Thanks

Comment: @Ferie I am having child_routes in my development version and root routes in node_modules

Comment: I do not think this is a good way of doing this. My way should be using modules and importing A into B or viceversa if you need it